# HTML Form and global variables: Why doesn't it recognize the global variable?

Tags: javascript

I've asked this question before but I did it poorly so no one has replied since I editing it. Anyway, if you look at the Javascript section below, the variables declared outside the function did not work specifically saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'p1' of undefined".  When I move them inside the function, they work.  I don't understand. I thought that by putting it outside the function, they would become global and would work.  Why doesn't it not work conceptually? When the function is invoked, shouldn't it be able to pick up the fact that the variables/properties declared/created outside the function exist?

**HTML**

```
<form name="percent">
        <table id="heading">
            <tr><td><h2>Enter information here:</h2></td></tr>
        <table id="meat">
            <tr>    
                <td>Percentage 1</td>
                <td class="denid"><input type="number" name="p1" class="inputB"></td>
                <td class="percent1">%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Denominator 1</td>
                <td><input type="number" name="d1" class="inputB"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Numerator 1</td>
                <td><span id="n1"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <td>Percentage 2</td>
                <td class-"denid"><input type="number" name="p2" class="inputB"></td>
                <td class="percent1">%</td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Denominator 2</td>
                <td><input type="number" name="d2" class="inputB"></td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Numerator 2</td>
                <td><span id="2"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="Compute" onclick="calculate()"></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var per1 = document.percent.p1.value;
var den1 = document.percent.d1.value;
var per2 = document.percent.p2.value;
var den2 = document.percent.d2.value;

function calculate () {
var numerator1 = (per1 * den1) / 100;
var numerator2 = (per2 * den2) / 100;

var numeratorT = numerator1 + numerator2;
document.getElementById("numeratorTotal").innerHTML=numeratorT;

var denominatorT = +den1 + +den2;
document.getElementById("denominatorTotal").innerHTML=denominatorT;

var weightedA = (numeratorT / denominatorT) * 100;
document.getElementById("weightedAvg").innerHTML=weightedA + "%";

}
```

Comment: Please define "don't work". Does it throw? Does it do nothing? Is there anything in the browser console window?

Comment: It specifically says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'p1' of undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to initialize global variables with input fields values they should be declared 
after the markup

as follows

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
   <form>
   <!-- your inputs and something something ....-->
   </form>
<script>
 //your global variables here declared by initializing them with input fields values;

</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok. I thought it had something to do with the form so this confirms it. So this is just a rule of JavaScript? How do I understand this better?

Comment: if script is before the input fields

script loaded first and scans whole document to find inputs if inputs are not loaded yet error will occur

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it doesn't work when you move the variables out of the function is because they get a value set right when the document loads. To get the values when `Compute` is clicked, you need to move the variables inside the function.

The other thing you can do is init the variables outside the function and then later on in the function give them a value.

```
var per1;
var den1;
var per2;
var den2;

function calculate () {
  per1 = document.percent.p1.value;
  den1 = document.percent.d1.value;
  per2 = document.percent.p2.value;
  den2 = document.percent.d2.value;

  var numerator1 = (per1 * den1) / 100;
  var numerator2 = (per2 * den2) / 100;

  var numeratorT = numerator1 + numerator2;
  document.getElementById("numeratorTotal").innerHTML=numeratorT;

  var denominatorT = +den1 + +den2;
  document.getElementById("denominatorTotal").innerHTML=denominatorT;

  var weightedA = (numeratorT / denominatorT) * 100;
  document.getElementById("weightedAvg").innerHTML=weightedA + "%";
}
```

This way you can still use the same variables somewhere else in another function.

Comment: Thank you. I learned something here. Now it makes sense why declaring a variable without assigning a value is done in practice.